# Deleting Duplicate Visible Rows

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I am trying to use the following VBA code to do two things.

1. Count the number of unique visible rows in a filtered worksheet.
2. Delete the duplicate rows

So far:

```
Function UniqueVisible(MyRange As Range) As Integer


    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(1)

    Dim R As Range
    Dim V() As String
    ReDim V(0 To MyRange.Count) As String


    For Each R In MyRange
        If (R.EntireRow.Hidden = False) Then
            For Index = 0 To UniqueVisible
                If (V(Index) = R.Value) Then
                    R.Delete
                    Exit For
                End If

                If (Index = UniqueVisible) Then
                    V(UniqueVisible) = R.Value
                    UniqueVisible = UniqueVisible + 1
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next R

End Function
```

This counts okay, and if I replace `R.Delete` with `MsgBox(R.Row)` I get the correct row number of the duplicate.

- `R.Delete` does nothing.
- `R.EntireRow.Delete` does nothing
- `ws.Rows(R.Row).Delete` does nothing.

**UPDATE**

This doesn't seem to be working

```
Function UniqueVisible(MyRange As Range) As Integer

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(1)

    Dim R As Range

    Dim Dup As Integer
    Dup = 0

    Dim Dups() As Integer
    ReDim Dups(0 To MyRange.Count) As Integer

    Dim V() As String
    ReDim V(0 To MyRange.Count) As String


    For Each R In MyRange
        If (R.EntireRow.Hidden = False) Then
            For Index = 0 To UniqueVisible
                If (V(Index) = R.Value) Then
                    Dups(Dup) = R.Row
                    Dup = Dup + 1
                    Exit For
                End If

                If (Index = UniqueVisible) Then
                    V(UniqueVisible) = R.Value
                    UniqueVisible = UniqueVisible + 1
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next R

    For Each D In Dups
        ws.Rows(D).Delete
    Next D

End Function
```

Comment: VB.Net or VBA? They are not the same thing and having both tags can only generate confusion.

Comment: The confusion is mine to begin with

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you're breaking a few rules here.

1. You cannot use a *function* to delete rows in VBA. It does not matter whether you are using the function as a *User Defined Function* (aka UDF) on the worksheet or calling it from a sub in a VBA project. A function is meant to return a value, not perform operations that modify the structure (or even the values other than its own cell) on a worksheet. In your case, it could return an array of row numbers to be deleted by a sub.
2. It is considered canonical practise to start from the bottom (or the right for columns) and work up when deleting rows. Working from the top to the bottom may skip rows when a row is deleted and you loop to the next one.

Here is an example where a sub calls the function to gather the count of the unique, visible entries and an array of rows to be removed.

```
Sub remove_rows()
    Dim v As Long, vDelete_These As Variant, iUnique As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets(1)

    vDelete_These = UniqueVisible(ws.Range("A1:A20"))

    iUnique = vDelete_These(LBound(vDelete_These))

    For v = UBound(vDelete_These) To (LBound(vDelete_These) + 1) Step -1 'not that we are working from the bottom up
        ws.Rows(vDelete_These(v)).EntireRow.Delete
    Next v

    Debug.Print "There were " & iUnique & " unique, visible values."

End Sub

Function UniqueVisible(MyRange As Range)
    Dim R As Range
    Dim uniq As Long
    Dim Dups As Variant
    Dim v As String

    ReDim Dups(1 To 1) 'make room for the unique count
    v = ChrW(8203) 'seed out string hash check with the delimiter

    For Each R In MyRange
        If Not R.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            If CBool(InStr(1, v, ChrW(8203) & R.Value & ChrW(8203), vbTextCompare)) Then
                ReDim Preserve Dups(1 To UBound(Dups) + 1)
                Dups(UBound(Dups)) = R.Row
            Else
                uniq = uniq + 1
                v = v & R.Value & ChrW(8203)
            End If
        End If
    Next R

    Dups(LBound(Dups)) = uniq  'stuff the unique count into the primary of the array

    UniqueVisible = Dups

End Function
```

Now, that is probably not how I would go about it. Seems easier to just write the whole thing into a single sub. However, understanding processes and limitations is important so I hope you can work with this.

Note that this does *not* have any error control. This should be present when dealing with arrays and deleting row in loops.

Comment: Yo. That looks great. I'm out if office now. I'll test ASAP. I didn't even know sub was a thing.

Comment: I don't get `v = ChrW(8203)` or the `InStr` Function call... the rest makes sense

Comment: I think I got it. You're setting `v` to a blank character, checking if the current row value is in `v` and if not, adding the current row value to `v` and repeating. Instead of using an array of strings, you are using a single string.

Comment: Why does  `uniq` need to be stuffed in `Dups` instead of directly into `UniqueVisible` ?

Comment: `ChrW(8203)` is unicode for a zero-length space. I've used it as a delimiter so that checking for *ace* does not return a false positive on *face*. `InStr` checks to see if a string is within another string. By collecting a string and concatenating with a delimiter that is very unlikely to be a part if the original value you are checking if *<delim><value><delim>* is within *<delim><value1><delim><value2><delim><value3><delim>*. If found, the value is a duplicate. If not found them add 1 to *uniq* and put the value into the string so it will be found as a duplicate if it crops up again.

Comment: @NonSecwitter - `UniqueVisible` return the full array of row numbers. I've reserved the first position in the array to carry back the *uniq* as well. The loop that actually removed the rows stops before it gets to the first position in the array. In this manner, both the rows to remove and the number of unique, visible entries can be carried back together.

Comment: So, `UniqueVisible[0]`  is equal to the count, and each element above `[0]` is a row to be deleted?

Comment: Yes, but you have to work backwards to delete the rows. If you don't and delete row 9, rows 10 becomes row 9 so the next loop tries to delete row 10 it is actually deleting the original row 11, not row 10.

Comment: Got it. I appreciate your time! I can now free myself from myself from having to create a report for someone else once a month

Comment: I tested this and it works great. Thanks again. I left the "UniqueVisible" as a separate function because it makes it quick and easy to get counts while filtering.

Answer (score 3):

You can't delete a row while you're looping through the rows.  You'll need to store the rows that need to be deleted in an array, and then loop through the array and delete the rows after it's done looping through the rows.

Comment: I didn't know that. I tried that, as shown above. Am I still doing that wrong?

Comment: Remember that the objects in the array are row objects, so you might just need to do "D.delete" instead of ws.Rows(D).Delete.  You've got the general idea now, but I don't know VBA well enough to be 100% sure why it's not working without actively debugging it.  Make sure it is actually putting objects into the array.

Comment: It is. I think the problem is that there are more elements in the array than rows to fill it. When it gets through all of the duplicates, and the next element is "0" it throws an error. I'll probably have to create a new array of size (range.count - UniqueVisible) and copy all of the values to avoid the problem.

Comment: Ideally, the array would be redimmed each time you need to add a row to it so it would never be larger than it needs to be.  If you are using VB .NET you can use an ArrayList object which is easier to work with.

Comment: Hmmm. Apparently (ws.Rows()) returns a read only object. I don't get how other people are using it, then....

Comment: Store the row numbers in the array, then reverse the array and loop through it to delete them by index number.  You have to reverse the array because if you delete row 1, for example, that will change all of the other row numbers and the rest of the delete will delete the wrong rows.

Comment: Every method of accessing a range from a worksheet returns a read only range... not quite sure what to do with that....

Comment: If you can't solve that then one option is to create a new spreadsheet and only add the rows you want to keep.